# the secret of the Tesla letter in The Prestige

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

In the movie The Prestige, I realized that

> Borden has a twin brother who he uses in tricks. Some kind of half life.

But I don't understand anything about that specific letter that Borden gave to Angier. He wrote Tesla on it. What was that about?
Is there a possibility that

> Tesla made a copy of Borden like Angier?